# grails externalized configuration chaning on the fly

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I'm trying to externalize my app configuration and make it possible to reload some values on the fly. For example - I'm using email plugin and want to externalize my mail box configuration and be able to change it without restarting the server. I've used

```
grails.config.locations = ["file:somedir/some-properties.properties"]
```

and discovered that properties are loaded properly. I use `grailsApplication.configuration.property.name` expression to access my properties. But I've found out that if to load application and then change some property in the file then in the application this property will have old value. Is there a way to make app load new properties from the file every time?

Comment: http://grails.org/plugin/external-config-reload

Comment: will this work for external Config.groovy as well? Can you please create an answer here with this link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below plugin, it should solve your problem

http://grails.org/plugin/external-config-reload